# How to display banner after three post?

Tags: php

Below is the code to display the post. That loads every 10 posts. And I want to display banner after 3 post. Can someone tell me, code to display banner after 3 post? By completing the code below. Thank you so much for your help.

```
<?php
        $stories = Wo_GetPosts(array('limit' => 10));
        if (count($stories) <= 0) {
          echo Wo_LoadPage('story/no-stories');
        } else {
          foreach ($stories as $wo['story']) {
            echo Wo_LoadPage('story/content');
          }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: You've clearly explained what you would like your code to do, but you have not presented us with any code that represents your attempts to achieve this - just the structure where this ephemeral code might fit.  Please provide an example of what you have attempted; StackOverflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: I have try this code, but not work. <?php
            $stories = Wo_GetPosts(array('limit' => 10));
            if (count($stories) == 3) {
              BANNER HERE
            } else {
              foreach ($stories as $wo['story']) {
                echo Wo_LoadPage('story/content');
              }
            }
            ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use `count()` in a way that this function is not intended.  Per the PHP documentation:

> Counts all elements in an array, or something in an object.
>   http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

What you need to do is create a counter variable that increments within your `foreach` loop, and when it hits 3 outputs the banner.  Your code might look something like this:

```
<?php

  $stories = Wo_GetPosts(array('limit' => 10));

  // No stories; output error
  if (count($stories) <= 0) 
    echo Wo_LoadPage('story/no-stories');

  // Stories exist; show them!
  } else {

    $count = 0;

    // Loop through $stories
    foreach ($stories as $wo['story']) {
      // Increment the value of $count by +1
      $count++; 

      if ($count == 3) {
        // Output my Banner here
      }

      echo Wo_LoadPage('story/content');
    }
  } 

?>
```

One thing I would note is that the above code only outputs a banner one time; when the value of `$count` is `3`.  You could adjust this to run ever 3rd story by changing the match from `if ($count ==3)` to `if ($count % 3 == 0)` which essentially reads as `If the value of $count is divisible by 3`.

Comment: awesome, perfect my brother. Thank you so much. This is I am looking for, you are brilliant. Thanks so much...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you create some HTML Code with this? If true, I'd use some Javascript for this purpose. Something like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="stories">
        <div>story 1</div>
        <div>story 2</div>
        <div>story 3</div>
        <div>story 4</div>
    </div> 


<script type="text/javascript">

$("#stories>div:nth-child(3)").after('<div class="banner">your bannery</div> ');
</script>

</body>
</html>
```